# The above error occurred in the <App> component: in App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, jsx, react-proptypes

I started the Knowthen Go/React tutorial and I've some problem with React.
When i try to launch my app, i've got this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHad5.png) and i can't figure out why.
Here's my github repo with all my sources: https://github.com/LaLauque/RealTImePlatform/tree/dev

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message can't really be much clearer. You're referencing `addChanel` - notice the typo, whereas in your code you have defined a method called `addChannel`.

As you might expect `addChanel` cannot be found as it does not exist.

You have made this mistake in two places: in App.jsx lines 8 and 29.